# Drag marker on Google maps and receive its updated position

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps-api-3

I got some code which is for seraching google maps and adding a marker.
Now my issue is to make this marker draggable (its easy) and get new coordinates of dragged marker (can't make it), to write it into mysql db. Here's code:

```
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.243240, 21.030295);
  var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 8,
   center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}




function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: results[0].geometry.location,

     }); 

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: results[0].geometry.location,
map: map,
draggable:true,
title:"Drag me!"


});



  var input = results[0].geometry.location; 

 document.getElementById("wypisz").innerHTML=input.lat();
  document.getElementById("wypisz2").innerHTML=input.lng();
//console.log(lat); 


 var input = results[0].geometry.location; 
var lat = input.lat();
var lng = input.lng();
$("#latValue").val(lat);
$("#lngValue").val(lng);


  } else {
  alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
  }
});


}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Help needed.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but could any1 write how to add posibility to have only one marker on this map ?

Comment: If you only want one marker, only create one (make it global).  Then if it exists, move it. [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_changeCircleRadius.html)